# dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cublas-9-1_9.1.85.3-1_amd64.deb (--unpack)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, cuda

When I am running sudo apt-get -f install, it shows dpkg: error processing. Please find the complete logs below and advise how to solve this. Should I remove the old version?

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Correcting dependencies... Done
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      cuda-cublas-9-1
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      cuda-cublas-9-1
    1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 553 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 50.1 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 56.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Get:1 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  cuda-cublas-9-1 9.1.85.3-1 [50.1 MB]
    Fetched 50.1 MB in 21s (2,313 kB/s)                                            
    (Reading database ... 415420 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../cuda-cublas-9-1_9.1.85.3-1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking cuda-cublas-9-1 (9.1.85.3-1) over (9.1.85-1) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cublas-9-1_9.1.85.3-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cublas-9-1_9.1.85.3-1_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error that you are getting is:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cublas-9-1_9.1.85.3-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
```

The "**trying to overwrite**" error implies that you have conflicting packages in your system.You can try overwriting the package (can be a bit risky)

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cublas-9-1_9.1.85.3-1_amd64.deb You need to remove that package
```

If that doesn't fix it, you can remove the package and re-install it

```
sudo dpkg -P cuda-cublas
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried: sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cublas-9-1_9.1.85.3-1_amd64.deb. I don't have any errors now.